# Getting Error while clicking on show history in eclips

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, history

I am getting below error when I go to team and click on show history .
I am using eclipse juno

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableLayout.<init>(Z)V
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.CVSHistoryTableProvider.createTree(CVSHistoryTableProvider.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.CVSHistoryPage.createTree(CVSHistoryPage.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.CVSHistoryPage.createControl(CVSHistoryPage.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.history.GenericHistoryView.doCreatePage(GenericHistoryView.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.createPage(PageBookView.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.partActivated(PageBookView.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.history.GenericHistoryView.showHistoryPageFor(GenericHistoryView.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.team.ui.TeamUI.showInputInView(TeamUI.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.team.ui.TeamUI.showHistoryFor(TeamUI.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.actions.ShowResourceInHistoryAction$1.run(ShowResourceInHistoryAction.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.repo.RepositoryManager.run(RepositoryManager.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.actions.CVSAction$2.run(CVSAction.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.actions.CVSAction$3.run(CVSAction.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.actions.CVSAction.run(CVSAction.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.actions.ShowResourceInHistoryAction.execute(ShowResourceInHistoryAction.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.actions.CVSAction.run(CVSAction.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.TeamAction.runWithEvent(TeamAction.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: Looks like you have a version of the Team/CVS code from a newer version of Eclipse

Comment: thanks for your response greg. Can you please let me know how can I fix it

Comment: Have you installed something in your Eclipse? It might be easiest to install a new copy of Eclipse (Kepler perhaps) in a new location. Your workspace will not be affected by the change.